# Angular 2 relative pathing from a named outlet

Tags: angular2-routing

After days of searching, I am unable to determine the right way to cause a component in a named router outlet to affect the primary routed component using relative pathing.

1. I've read [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)
2. I've read [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html)
3. I've read [Dreams Do Come True!...](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)
4. I've searched all over StackOverflow

The routes:

```js
let routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth/portfolio/home/1', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { 
path: 'auth/:module', 
component: AuthComponent, 
children: [
  { path: 'home/:value', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'home2/:value', component: Home2Component},
  { path: 'details', component: DetailComponent, outlet: 'aux'},
  { path: 'details2', component: Detail2Component, outlet: 'aux'}
]
  }
];
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uoUBG6yDfNb6P0oLKN16?p=preview) showing the issues.

1. The AuthComponent's links work just fine.  They can change the child component or the named router outlet's component just like the documentation says.
2. The Detail or Home components are fighting me.  With some experimentation, I've been able to get the absolute pathing to work (Home2, Detail2) but it isn't the solution for our application.
3. I know that I can use router.navigateByUrl(...), but that is still not relative without doing string matching/regex/whatever

**Question:** What is the right syntax for getting a child routed component to affect a sibling component in a named routed outlet and vice versa?  If possible, can you respond with a working plunker?

**UPDATE 1:**
As a short-term hackaround, I've created an AuthRouterService that performs the routing for the child components up in the AuthComponent.  The AuthRouterService is in the Providers array for the AuthComponent, so all the children get the one service.  I'm leaving this question here in case someone finds the proper syntax that negates the need for this hackaround.  I'll mark it completed with this hackaround in about a week if I don't hear back.

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VfJhhExNxXhSSnsZ1PiF?p=preview) here for the AuthRoutingService and how I used it as a hackaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a short-term hackaround, I've created an AuthRouterService that performs the routing for the child components up in the AuthComponent. The AuthRouterService is in the Providers array for the AuthComponent, so all the children get the one service. I'm leaving this question here in case someone finds the proper syntax that negates the need for this hackaround. I'll mark it completed with this hackaround in about a week if I don't hear back.